# Limit characters returned in oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to limit this field to 4000 characters. How do I limit it on the list agg? Thanks.

```
LISTAGG(ORDER_IMPRESSION.IMPRESSION, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ORDER_IMPRESSION.LINE)
```

Comment: The Data Warehouse Insider blog has a relevant entry here, https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/entry/managing_overflows_in_listagg.

Answer (score 2):

Only with a bit of effort.  Something like this:

```
select listagg((case when running_len < 4000 then oi.impression end), ',') within group (order by oi.line)
from (select oi.*,
             sum(length(oi.impression) + 1) over (partition by ?? order by oi.line) as running_len
      from order_impression oi
     ) oi
group by ??;
```

This calculates the running length and only aggregates values that do not exceed the length.  The `??` is whatever you are using for aggregation.  This does assume that `line` is unique, so the `order by` is stable.

This will not include the `impression` that exceeds the length -- and nothing after that.  It does not cut the impression off.  That logic is possible, but it does complicate the query.

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate a running total of the string length (using the `SUM(...) OVER (...)` analytic function) and then use this to truncate the string to 4000 characters:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(
         CASE
           WHEN prev_len >= 4000 THEN NULL
           WHEN prev_len + len <= 4000 THEN value
           ELSE SUBSTR( value, 1, 4000 - prev_len )
         END
       ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY line ) AS value
FROM   (
  SELECT impression,
         line,
         LENGTH( impression ) AS len,
         COALESCE(
           SUM( 1 + LENGTH( impression ) )
             OVER ( ORDER BY line ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING ),
           0
         ) AS prev_len
  FROM   order_impression
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom aggregation function to aggregate `VARCHAR2`s into a `CLOB`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CLOBAggregation AS OBJECT(
  value CLOB,

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT CLOBAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    value       IN     VARCHAR2
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    returnValue    OUT CLOB,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    ctx         IN OUT CLOBAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY CLOBAggregation
IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT CLOBAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    ctx := CLOBAggregation( NULL );
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    value       IN     VARCHAR2
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF value IS NULL THEN
      NULL;
    ELSIF self.value IS NULL THEN
      self.value := value;
    ELSE
      self.value := self.value || ',' || value;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    returnValue    OUT CLOB,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    returnValue := self.value;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    ctx         IN OUT CLOBAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF self.value IS NULL THEN
      self.value := ctx.value;
    ELSIF ctx.value IS NULL THEN
      NULL;
    ELSE
      self.value := self.value || ',' || ctx.value;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;
END;
/

CREATE FUNCTION CLOBAgg( value VARCHAR2 )
RETURN CLOB
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING CLOBAggregation;
/
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR( CLOBAGG( IMPRESSION ), 4000 )
FROM   (
  SELECT   IMPRESSION
  FROM     ORDER_IMPRESSION
  ORDER BY line
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a 12.2 early adopter, you can use the ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE clause...

[ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/listagg-function-enhancements-12cr2#handling-overflow-errors)