# Oracle: Count non-null fields for each column in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a query to count the total number of non-null values *for each* column in a table. Since my table has hundreds of columns I'm looking for a solution that only requires me to input the table name.

Perhaps using the result of:

```
select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='ORDERS';
```

to get the column names and then a subquery to put counts against each column name? The additional complication is that I only have read-only access to the DB so I can't create any temp tables.

Slightly out of my league with this one so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the query in SQL or using a spreadsheet.  Then run the query.

For instance, assuming that your column names are simple and don't have special characters:

```
select replace('select ''[col]'', count([col]) from orders union all ',
               '[col]', COLUMN_NAME
              ) as sql
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'ORDERS';
```

(Of course, this can be adapted for more complex column names, but I'm trying to show the idea.)

Then copy the code, remove the final `union all` and run it.

You can put this in one string if there are not too many columns:

```
select listagg(replace('select ''[col]'', count([col]) from orders',
                       '[col]', COLUMN_NAME
                      ), ' union all '
               ) within group (order by column_name) as sql
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'ORDERS';
```

You can also use `execute immediate` using the same query, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: This will fail for any case-sensitive column names or column names containing non alpha-numeric characters (comma, quote, bracket, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with the results row-ar rather than column-ar:

```
SELECT 'SELECT ''dummy'', 0 FROM DUAL' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
  ' UNION ALL SELECT ''' || 
  column_name ||
  ''', COUNT(' || 
  column_name || 
  ') FROM ' || 
  TABLE_NAME
FROM 
  all_tab_columns
WHERE 
  table_name = 'ORDERS'
```

This is an "SQL that writes an SQL" that you can then copy and run to get your answers. Should make a resultset that looks like:

> SELECT 'dummy', 0 FROM dual
>
> UNION ALL SELECT 'col1', COUNT(col1) FROM ORDERS
>
> UNION ALL SELECT 'col2', COUNT(col2) FROM ORDERS
>
> ...

If you want your results column-ar:

```
SELECT 'SELECT '
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  'COUNT(' || 
  column_name ||
  ') as count_' || 
  column_name || 
  ', ' || 
  TABLE_NAME
FROM 
  all_tab_columns
WHERE 
  table_name = 'ORDERS'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'null as dummy_column FROM ORDERS'
```

Should make a resultset that looks like:

> SELECT
>
> COUNT(col1) as count_col1,
>
> COUNT(col2) as count_col2,
>
> ...
>
> null as dummycoll FROM orders

Caveat: I don't have oracle installed anywhere I can test these, it's written from memory and may need some debugging

Comment: This will fail for any case-sensitive column names or column names containing non alpha-numeric characters (comma, quote, bracket, etc).

Comment: Call that an exercise for the reader. I know that people sometimes ask on SO because they need spoonfeeding, but what the heck; sometimes you just gotta take a chance on people being able to work something as basic as "breathe in, breathe out" out for themselves - it's not like they wouldn't get a sensible error message to guide them

Answer (score 0):

This will generate the SQL to get the counts in columns and will handle case sensitive column names and column names with non-alpha-numeric characters:

```
SELECT 'SELECT '
       || LISTAGG(
         'COUNT("' || column_name || '") AS "' || column_name || '"',
         ', '
       ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY column_id )
       || ' FROM "' || table_name || '"' AS sql
FROM   ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'ORDERS'
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```

or, if you have a large number of columns that is generating a string longer than 4000 characters you can use a [custom aggregation function to aggregate `VARCHAR2`s into a `CLOB`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43000237/1509264) and then do:

```
SELECT 'SELECT '
       || CLOBAgg( 'COUNT("' || column_name || '") AS "' || column_name || '"' )
       || ' FROM "' || table_name || '"' AS sql
FROM   ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'ORDERS'
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.

Comment: @h0dges [Create a user defined aggregation function to generate a `CLOB`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43000237/1509264) and use `CLOBAGG( ... )` rather than `LISTAGG( .. ) WITHIN GROUP ( ... )`.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 19 (I used similar code in Ora 12, maybe that works too), this works without generating another select to execute:

```
select * from
(
    select table_name, column_name,
           to_number( extractvalue( xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(to_char(substr('||column_name||',1,1))) c from '||table_name)) ,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) count
    from all_tab_columns where owner = user
) 
--where table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
;
```

It will create XML with count, from which it extracts the current count. The substr and to_char functions here are used to extract first character, so it will works with CLOB columns also