# How I can use 'listagg' with clob

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

I need to concatenate several clubs into one string with a delimiter between them and put it into the club. But I have received different errors with the same meaning - The combined string is so large.

I have next sql:

```
select listagg(clob_column, '***') as text, doc_id
from table
group by doc_id;
```

Where clob_column may be really long string.
How can I concatenate cells from one column with a delimiter in 19c Oracle DB?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LISTAGG function: "result of string concatenation is too long"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795220/listagg-function-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long). Or [Oracle - convert column values to comma separated values as CLOB without using XMLAGG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69039501/oracle-convert-column-values-to-comma-separated-values-as-clob-without-using-x)