# LISTAGG 4000 Character Limit - Result of string concatenation is too long

Tags: oracle, clob, varchar2

```
 select t.name, listagg(t.text) 
   from user_source t 
  group by t.name;
```

I am trying to execute the code above but since varchar2 is limited by 4000 chars it throws error. I tried to convert listagg to xml but I could not solve the

> ```
> ORA-64451: Conversion of special character to escaped character failed.
> ```

error. I also tried the answers from other posts from various websites including stackoverflow.

I do not want to truncate the string, also I can't change **`MAX_STRING_SIZE`** parameter.

This example below throws **`ORA-64451`** as well. I tried but could not solve the problem.

```
select rtrim(
             xmlagg(
                    xmlelement(e, to_clob(t.TEXT), '; ').extract('//text()')
                   ).GetClobVal(),
             ',')
  from user_source t;
```

Comment: what is the data type of t.text?, size, also.

Comment: https://paulzipblog.wordpress.com/2019/04/23/a-solution-to-listaggs-4000-byte-limit/

Comment: You may also create your own aggregate function to operate on clobs

Comment: @OldProgrammer unfortunately I couldn't solve the ORA-64451 error in your answer. but creating the my own aggregate function is worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I know is posted somewhere in the Internet... You could probably just google for it. It basically consist of few steps:

1. Creating a collection type to store each text value to concatenate

```
create or replace type string_array_t as table of VARCHAR2(4000);
```

2. Creating a PL/SQL function which takes `string_array_t` as parameter and returns concatenated text as `CLOB`:

```
create or replace function 
  string_array2clob(
    p_string_array string_array_t
    ,p_delimiter varchar2 default ','
) RETURN CLOB IS
  v_string CLOB;
BEGIN
  -- inside is a loop over p_string_array to concatenate all elements
  --
  -- below is just a draft because in real you should use a while loop
  -- to handle sparse collection and you should put some checks to handle not initialized collection
  -- and other important cases
  -- furthermore it's better to create additional varchar2 variable as a buffer
  -- and convert that buffer to clob when it's full for a better performance
  for indx in p_string_array.first..p_string_array.last loop
    v_string := v_string || to_clob(p_string_array(indx) || p_delimiter);
  end loop;

  RETURN substr(v_string, 1, nvl(length(v_string),0) - nvl(length(p_delimiter),0));
END string_array2clob;
/
```

3. Aggregate query as usual but using `cast` and `collect` instead of `listagg` and at the end convert it to `clob` with function from step above:

```
select t.name, string_array2clob(cast(collect(t.text order by t.line) as string_array_t ), p_delimiter => chr(10)) as text
   from user_source t 
  group by t.name;
```

If your query is not just an example of concept and really you're trying to get a source of some object in database, then you should read about `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` function. It's made for it.

Comment: The solution that you suggested is perfectly solved the problem. But I can't use the dbms_metadata.get_ddl function because I am not privileged user. It throws ORA-31603 error which I am not able to get rid of.

Comment: @mertcan This is inefficient as it is going to store the data in memory twice. Once in the collection and then a second time when you concatenate the string in the function. It would be better to use a user-defined aggregation function which will only store the data once.

Comment: @MT0 thanks for the info. I will take a look at your "custom aggregation function" solution from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999390/limit-characters-returned-in-oracle-sql-query/43000237#43000237)

Comment: @MT0 does solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999390/limit-characters-returned-in-oracle-sql-query/43000237#43000237) is what you have in mind? If yes, then I will take a look into it and benchmark it, because last time I used custom aggregate function it was soooo slow, I had to find another solution. I admit my query will use double size of memory but probably only for the limited number of rows (fetch size). I have never had problems with it and query time is usually more important for me.

Comment: @mertcan - you need `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` or to be the owner of the object to see its definition. So log in as the owner or ask for a `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` privilege (it might not be accepted by DBA because it gives access in sensitive area).